# Adding hour and 0 count where it is missing from data

Tags: r, dataframe, hour

My dataframe looks like this.  If there is no data for the hour there isnt even a row for the hour of day.  The hours in the data go from 0-23 representing 24 hours in the day.  Is there a way to add the hours for the date with a zero count with maybe a second dataframe as a lookup or something?

df 
        date            hour    count

```
    2018-01-15        08    4682
    2018-01-15        09    406
    2018-01-16        05    3359
    2018-01-16        06    11926
    2018-01-16        07    42602
```

I would like the dataframe to look like this:

df 
      date          hour    count

```
  2018-01-15          01    0
  2018-01-15          02    0
  2018-01-15          03    0
  2018-01-15          04    0
  2018-01-15          06    0
  2018-01-15          06    0
  2018-01-15          07    0
  2018-01-15          08    4682
  2018-01-15          09    406
  2018-01-15          10    0
  ....
  2018-01-16          05    3359
  2018-01-16          06    11926
  2018-01-16          07    42602    
  2018-01-16          08    0
  2018-01-16          09    0
  2018-01-16          10    0
  2018-01-16          11    0
  ....
```

Comment: `tidyr::complete(DF, V1, V2 = 1:24, fill=list(V3 = 0))` is one way, see https://stackoverflow.com/q/45992101/

Comment: @Frank That worked!  Thank you very much!

Comment: It does both. Try it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `expand.grid` to get the cartesian product of the column values, and use join operation in `data.table` package

```
library('data.table')
df2 <- expand.grid(date = unique(df1$date), hour = 0:23, count = 0L, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
setDT(df2)[df1, count := i.count, on = .(date, hour)]
```

using cross join `CJ` in `data.table` for creating the `df2` data

```
df2 <- CJ(date = unique(df1$date), hour = 0:23, count = 0L)
df2[df1, count := i.count, on = .(date, hour)]
```

Data:

```
df1 <- read.table(text='2018-01-15        08    4682
2018-01-15        09    406
                  2018-01-16        05    3359
                  2018-01-16        06    11926
                  2018-01-16        07    42602 ', stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
colnames(df1) <- c('date', 'hour', 'count')
```

Answer (score 3):

As mentionned by others, you could use `dplyr` and `tidyr`.
For your specific column names, this comes down to:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data = "date hour count
2018-01-15        08    4682
2018-01-15        09    406
2018-01-16        05    3359
2018-01-16        06    11926
2018-01-16        07    42602"

df <- read.table(text=data, header = T)
df

df %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  complete(hour = full_seq(1:24, 1), fill = list(count = 0))
```

Which yields:

```
# A tibble: 48 x 3
# Groups:   date [2]
   date        hour count
   <fct>      <dbl> <dbl>
 1 2018-01-15    1.    0.
 2 2018-01-15    2.    0.
 3 2018-01-15    3.    0.
 4 2018-01-15    4.    0.
 5 2018-01-15    5.    0.
 6 2018-01-15    6.    0.
 7 2018-01-15    7.    0.
 8 2018-01-15    8. 4682.
 9 2018-01-15    9.  406.
10 2018-01-15   10.    0.
# ... with 38 more rows
```